# Editing multiple plots in Rstudio

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

One interesting feature of RStudio is it allows to save multiple plots generated from a script. This however opens up the problem of how to edit multiple plots. My issue at the moment is adding lines to histograms using the abline() function. This function was designed however to work with the last plot generated by the environment. One way of course would be ad the lines as soon as the plot is generated, however I have to calculate the coordinates at the end of the algorithm, by then I have transformed the data and generated multiple plots from it. So I was wondering if there isn't a way to tell R to search for a given plot and add the line to it. I read abline() documentation but found nothing regarding it. One can always save the data necessary to generate the plot and generate it at the end of the script, but I was wondering if there isn't a less consuming memory method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get around this issue is:

1.Save your graphics as variables, for ex: hist_1=hist(x, plot=FALSE)

2.Write any code u like, for ex: very complicated code give y as a number for output

3.plot(hist_1)

4.abline(hist_1, v=y)

gives a general idea of how to edit multiple plots without having to save multiple copies of datasets and without overloading Rstudio interface. Works well with the R ubuntu terminal too.